# How to embed a excel sheet inside the property sheet of a flex component?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml, flashdevelop

I am trying to create a custom component in flex using mxml. I have created the property sheet for the custom component but it needs a button which onclick has to point to a cell in excel sheet from which data can be retrieved. How to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [as3xls](http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/).